# IE compatibility issue in vue project

Tags: vue.js

I am currently using vue.
There are two problems.

1. When I open the page with IE browser, I get an async function syntax error.
   I thought it was a js compatibility problem, and I set up babel-loader, but I still get an error.
   Are there any problems with the settings below?
2. The firebase/messaging library does not work in IE and Safari.
   The error doesn't seem to occur in IE, but in Firefox
   The library polyfill does not work or does not convert. Is there a problem with the barbell settings below?
   This is the project webpack and `enter code here`related library version.

"@babel/cli": "^7.13.16",
"@babel/core": "^7.14.2",
"@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator": "^7.13.15",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.14.2",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.2",
"webpack": "^5.37.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "targets": "> 0.25%, not dead",
          "ie": "11",
          "safari":"14"
        },
        "debug": true
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        // "absoluteRuntime": false,
        "corejs": false,
        // "helpers": true,
        "regenerator": true,
        // "useESModules": false
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", { "corejs": 3 }]]
```

babel-loader

```
{
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '/node_modules/@firebase'),
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              // ['@babel/preset-env', '@vue/app', {
              //   targets: "ie 11",
              //   useBuiltIns: "usage",
              //   corejs: "3"
              // }]
              ["@babel/preset-env", {
                "targets": {
                  "browserslist": "> 0.25%, not dead"
                },
                "useBuiltIns": "usage",
                "corejs":3,
                "shippedProposals": true
              }]
            ]
          }
        }
      },
```

Comment: What version Vue are you using? Vue 3 doesn't support IE11 as it requires features that can't be polyfilled afaik

Comment: "vue": "^2.6.12" use